# create DOC file in actionscript/flex/air

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

How can I make a word file (.doc) from flash builder (air aplication)? Is there any library to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is http://code.google.com/p/rtflex/ which lets you create RTF Files that can be opened in Word.

Comment: this library is not use for my problem..but i make other result..thans for help